# listoffigures left aligned with koma-script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, alignment

I did not really understand the koma-script manual when reading the chapter about the alignment of a List of Figures. What construct has to be used to get the \listoffigures left aligned? A LOF File is prepared through the URL.
[abbildungsverzeichnis.lof](https://wwwu.aau.at/hjele/latex_examples/abbildungsverzeichnis.lof)

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,toc=listofnumbered,headinclude,footinclude,index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\parindent 5.5mm
\def\captionsngerman{
\def\listfigurename{Abbildungsverzeichnis}}%

\begin{document}
\listoffigures%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KOMA-Script class option `listof=flat`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,toc=listofnumbered,listof=flat,headinclude,footinclude,index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\setparsizes{5.5mm}{0pt}{0pt plus 1fil}% see KOMa-Script manual
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}% see KOMA-Script manual

\begin{document}
\listoffigures%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\end{document}
```

After three LaTeX runs you get:

[image]

As an alternative, you can remove the indent for `figure` entries:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,toc=listofnumbered,headinclude,footinclude,index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\setparsizes{5.5mm}{0pt}{0pt plus 1fil}% see KOMa-Script manual
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}% see KOMA-Script manual

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{default}{figure}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thx, this seems to be the easiest way. Harald

Answer (score 1):

Can't test it with your .lof file. However, the KOMA-Script manual contains a section about customising such lists. Chapter 15.2 in my German manual mentions `\setuptoc` as the relevant command and `noindent` as a possible option, so `\setuptoc{lof}{noindent}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, toc=listofnumbered, headinclude, footinclude, index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\parindent 5.5mm
\def\captionsngerman{
\def\listfigurename{Abbildungsverzeichnis}}%

\setuptoc{lof}{noindent}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\captionof{figure}{First figure}
\captionof{figure}{Second figure}
\captionof{figure}{Yet another figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, this works. Harald