# thispagestyle empty on printindex

Tags: koma-script, indexing, pagestyle

I tried to get an empty pagestyle on the first page of an index, as I did for all chapters and lists, but failed.

[image: NotEmptyPageStyle]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,toc=listofnumbered,listof=flat,headinclude,footinclude,index=numbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\parindent 5.5mm
\def\captionsngerman{
\def\indexname{MyIndex}}%
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Huhu \index{huhu}
{\printindex\thispagestyle{empty}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The KOMA-Script manual recommends to use `\setparsizes` instead of directly changing `\parindent`. Additionally [your redefinition of `\captionsgerman` would add an unwanted space](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_AvoidSpaces/) to every switch to language `ngerman`. I've shown both improvements already in [my answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678910/277964).

Comment: And you don't need option `twoside` nor package `emptypage` with `scrbook`. `twoside` is the default and instead of `emptypage` there is option `cleardoublepage` (with `cleardoublepage=empty` as default since KOMA-Script 3.00).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're using (but the braces are useless) will apply `\thispagestyle{empty}` to the last page of the index, if used with a standard class. With a standard class you might do

```
\AddToHook{env/theindex/after}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

However this won't work with `scrbook`, which applies `\thispagestyle{\indexpagestyle}` and defines `\indexpagestyle` to be `plain`.

Solution: renew the command `\indexpagestyle`.

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  twoside,
  toc=listofnumbered,
  listof=flat,
  headinclude,
  footinclude,
  index=numbered,
  cleardoublepage=empty,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\addto\captionsngerman{\def\indexname{MyIndex}}% not \def\captionsngerman !!!

\makeindex
\renewcommand{\indexpagestyle}{empty}

\begin{document}

Huhu \index{huhu}

\printindex\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of points to note:

1. don't use `emptypage` with `scrbook`, but the relevant class option as shown in the code
2. don't do `\def\captionsngerman`, but `\addto\captionsngerman`.

Comment: I am recoding a book which code comes out of the 1990s. Therefore I do have some older constructs as \def\captionsngerman. I changed it. Many thanks. This empty page at index start works fine. Harald

Comment: Just a note: `cleardoublepage=empty` is the default for `scrbook` for several years.

Comment: I did not see any difference with or without. That's why:-) Cheers Harald